# SharePoint 2013 Search Host Web via App

Tags: 2013, search, sharepoint-addin, search-scope

2 Questions:
1) How can we scope search results for a SharePoint hosted app to a single host web list?
2) Is it possible to programatically return the URL for a specific Host Web List to the App?

Details:
In our SharePoint 2013 Hosted App we're attempting to return results from a SharePoint Host Web list. We're able to successfully return results using the REST Search Service using this example: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Perform-a-1bf3e87d

However, we don't know how to scope the search to only a single list. Another possibility would be to know the URL for the list and we can manually compare Search Results with our list URL to filter only the results we would like.

I'd love any insight anyone may have.

Comment: You should read up on KQL to be able to better use the search API, for example using Managed properties to filter http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee558911(v=office.15)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add "`Path:http://urlofyourlist`" to you KQL query.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Matthew. Since this is an App we may deploy to multiple environments we may not always have the URL path to our list. Currently we're returning all results from the search and looking through the resultant URLs for our list name in them and only displaying those results. Just looking for a way to know the exact path for our specific list every time would help.

Comment: If you are creating the list in the Host Web, can't you just add the Host Web URL to your query?